# 3d Models in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, 3d, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am using model_viewer_plus: ^1.7.0 in flutter to display 3d objects but I need a way to select the different objects and cant seem to find a way to do this.

So I have tried flutter_cube but that has a terrible render of objects, and a few other dependencies. I am basically wanting the object that has been made in blender out of many objects to have selectable parts in the app. So a human would have an arm you could select and that would highlight for example.

Thank you in advance